# Google signIn do not working in release-mode apk (решение проблемы)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Делюсь решением проблемы авторизации через Google-Sign-In в релизной версии проекта. Необходимо сделать следующие шаги:

Чтобы получить релизный код SHA-1 требуется:

```
1. Найти на диске служебную программу «keystore». 
На моём компьютере она находится - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin. 
2. На свободном поле в папке, в которой находится файл «keystore», 
нажать шифт и правую кнопку мыши. В контекстном меню выбрать: 
«Открыть окно PowerShell здесь».
3. Откроется окно PowerShell.
4. Вначале будет запись: PS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin>
5. найти расположение файла-ключа, созданного для данного проекта в 
Андроид Студии. Например - C:\Users\Desktop\key_1.jks.
6. в конце строки, с соблюдением всех пробелов, вставить:
.\keytool -exportcert -keystore "C:\Users\Desktop\key_1.jks" -list -v
7. появится запрос на пароль от файла-ключа: Enter keystore password:
8. нажать Enter
9. или ввести пароль, который мы определили при создании файла-ключа
в Студии.
10. Enter
11. появится информация с кодами:
***
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  *****14:84:*****
     SHA1: ***BA:***:2E:********
     SHA256: *****88:***:32:91******
****
12. скопировать код SHA1:
13. в консоли GoogleDeveloper (https://console.developers.google.com/)
нажать на кнопку «Создать учётные данные». 
14. Выбрать «Идентификатор клиента OAuth
15. выбрать Android
16. откроется бланк заполнения.
17. Придумать название клиента.
18. Вставить ключ SHA-1, полученный выше в  окне PowerShell.
19. Вставить пакет, скопированный в Студии (находится вначале каждого
 джава-файла или в манифесте).
20. «Создать».
21. Создастся новый релизный ключ.
22. После этого можно создавать в Студии релизную версию проекта и
 запускать его отдельно от Студии или выкладывать в Маркет.
23. Авторизация проходит и сохраняется на устройстве.
24. Предполагаю, что для авторизации через Firebase потребуются
 дальнейшие шаги:
25. этот же код надо будет вставить в консоли Firebase: 
26. выбираем проект
27. наверху «Project Overview»/(шестерёнка)/Настройки проекта
28. Крутим вниз
29. «Добавить контрольную сумму»
30. вставить SHA-1 и SHA-256
```

Comment: Само решение лучше перенести в ответ - они как раз для этого)